# error Duplicate entry in update

Tags: mysql, sql-update, duplicates

i have table ams2 with 3 PK toid,formid,sendat

the problem is wen i want to update  in to the table i have errer Duplicate entry

Table structer:

```
CREATE TABLE `ams2` (
  `toid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `fromid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` text,
  `ismsl` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `sendat` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `readit` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`toid`,`fromid`,`sendat`),
  KEY `ams2_ibfk_1` (`fromid`,`name`),
  CONSTRAINT `ams2_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fromid`, `name`) REFERENCES `allclient` (`id`, `name`),
  CONSTRAINT `ams2_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`toid`) REFERENCES `allclient` (`id`)
) 



update ams2
    set readit =true
    where fromid=2 and toid =1 and sendat <= '2014-03-16 18:07:37'
```

the error message :

```
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '1-2-2014-03-20 02:01:53' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

i want mySQL query edit just readit column without edit by default the other columns

Please help !!

---

### I FUND SOLUTION

use alter table and modify sendat and delete this option  ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

let it like this 
sendat` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: If you want to insert into the table, why are you using an `update` statement?

Comment: well the key is not on sendat. You have a unique constraint on three fields i can see the values 1, 2 ,2014-03-20 02:01:53 which is causing the duplicate. Do you have a unique index that include readit field?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759615/mysql-on-duplicate-key-update)